# Getting selected node path or depth tree view in angular JS or depth

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, treeview, treenode

I want to get the selected node path from root in tree view by using AngularJS. I have seen this link. It is used to get only selected node like subUser2. But i want to display selected Node path or depth like user/subUser2.

If i select subUser2 : then display User/subUser2

jsfiddle.net/eu81273/8LWUc/18/

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we will add to HTML: `<pre>{{currentNode|json}}</pre>` we can see:

```
{
  "roleName": "subUser2-1-1",
  "roleId": "role1211",
  "children": [],
  "selected": "selected"
}
```

Now the `roleId` is unique, in our case its `role1211` where `1211` represents parent indexes:

root -> 1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 1

By this way its pretty easy to write single method that runs in loop on tree model and fetch child according to `root -> 1 -> 2 -> 1 -> 1`

Comment: [link]http://jsfiddle.net/eu81273/8LWUc/18/  Please see this. I want to use the same script, but i need to display when i click the subUser2-1-1 is "User/subUser2-1/subUser2-1-1" instead of subUser2-1-1

Comment: Well, I showed you the direction. You need to write method that splits `roleId` and extract `1 2 1 1`. After, you can just fetch the names and build the path.

Comment: Can you please see this Json object tree view. [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20630281/get-leaf-node-depth-from-tree-view-in-angularjs/20630702?noredirect=1#20630702  for this how can i extract the child depth.